# Find expected value of given random Variable $X$, where $X$ equals payoff to the better.

Tags: probability, expected-value

In a state lottery a five-digit integer is selected at random. If a player
bets 1 dollar on a particular number, the payoff (if that number is selected)
is $500$ dollar minus the $1$ dollar paid for the ticket. Let X equal the payoff to the better.
Find the expected value of X.

I don't know where to begin to solve this problem? Any guidance or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

- What is the probability a particular ticket wins?
- If it does win, what is the net gain?
- What is the probability a particular ticket loses?
- If it does lose, what is the net gain? (it will be negative)

Combine these to find the overall expected net gain